# Specify one generic but infer another from usage

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

I have a function which returns a value in roughly the same shape as the input. The real function is more complicated but the situation can be simplified to this:

```js
function inferFromUsage<T>(value: T) {
  return () => value
}

const return10 = inferFromUsage(10)
// inferred type: () => number
```

Now let's assume I wanted to use another generic type while still inferring the one from usage:

```js
function specifyOne<T, U>(value: U) {
  return (arg: T) => value
}

specifyOne<string>(10)
// Expected: (arg: string) => number
// Actual: Expected 2 type arguments, but got 1.
```

Is there a way to continue to infer one of the generic types while specifying another one?

Comment: TLDR: Its not possible with one function. But you can use a technique called currying

Comment: @TobiasS. Too bad. At least now I know. Thanks!